# PHP Instert will not insert into Database

Tags: php, mysqli

(so to begin I'm a high school student so not the greatest with the lingo so try your best to guide rather than tell if you can) When using insert to put data into my database from the website it appears to work but nothing appears in the database but no error codes.

I am using Mysqli, PHP, and Wampserver to run a local server and the website will not send data to the Database.

```PHP
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

?>
Sign Up<br>
<form method="post" action="">

Username: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br>
password: <input type="password" name="user_pass"><br>
password <Check: input type="password" name="user_pass_check"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="user_email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>


<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_pass,  user_email) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_name'])."', '".sha1($_POST['user_pass'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_email'])."', NOW(), 0)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Something went wrong';
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    } else {
        echo "you have successfully registered. you can now <a href='signin.php'>sign in</a> and start posting";
    }
}
}

include 'footer.php'?>
```

In my file used for connection

```PHP
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$dbname = 'seqevents';
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) or die("cannot connect");

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_level'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = 0;
}
```

I receive no error messages and nothing happens on the website it just reloads and gets rid of any input within the text boxes.

Comment: Seems clear your code isn't even hitting your conditional. I'd recommend dumping out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to see if it's what you expect. A good habit of debugging is when you're not sure why you're not getting somewhere, dump out the variables that should get you there (or setup XDebug, though that can be a bit complicated).

Comment: You have got an extra `}` hanging in the first file.

Answer (score 1):

First the (likely) problem, then some other important pointers:

When you insert, you insert set 3 columns (user_name,user_pass,user_email) and then load 5 values into it (`NOW()` and `0`) are extra, it has no clue where to place those values.

---

- **DO NOT USE MD5**. If you're thinking "yeah, but my site isnt very interesting, why cares" read this line again. **DO NOT USE MD5**. Or sha1:

  > **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.  – [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman)
- Use prepared statements. mysqli_real_escape_string is a good first step, but not adequite. Prepared statements secure the query for you. Bit more complex, *a lot* more secure.
- I suggest removing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`. What if you have two forms on your page? You're stuck. Instead, give your submit button a name like `submitRegForm`. Then you can do `if( isset($_POST['submitRegForm']) )`
- **DO NOT USE MD5 OR SHA1**

Comment: There is probably no reason to link my username to your post. I believe the comment was worded originally by @MagnusEriksson Either way the content is most important.